# How do you declare PHONY targets as default actions with shake?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I'm in the process of converting a Makefile into a Shakefile, and I'm not sure how to handle PHONY make targets (`clean`, `install`, etc.). I tried something like:

```
main = shake shakeOptions $ do
  want ["install"]
  "install" *> \_ -> do
    need ["mytarget"]
    system' "ln" ["-s", "mytarget", "linkname"]
```

It succeeds at create the symlinks, but reports an error "Error, rule "install" failed to build file: install".

So, if not with the "want" action, how do I declare that the default target I want to run is a phony one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In shake-0.10.1 and above you can use the `phony` function to write:

```
main = shake shakeOptions $ do
  want ["install"]
  phony "install" $ do
    need ["mytarget"]
    system' "ln" ["-s", "mytarget", "linkname"]
```

This should do exactly what you want, and does not require a fake file to be produced. In addition, you may want to use `shakeArgs` rather than `shake` so that the user can select `install` from the command line, or chose another target such as clean.

Comment: changing accepted answer to this one, since this is exactly what I wanted indeed. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 1):

In shake-0.9 and below phony targets are a bit of a weak spot in Shake - you can do them, but they are a more verbose and manual than they should be. Here are a few options:

**Have the install rule produce a file**

As a very simple solution, just add `writeFile' "install" ""` at the bottom of the `install` rule. This produces a dummy file, but it will rerun every time `mytarget` changes. If you want it to run every time `install` is requested (like a phony would in make), just add `alwaysRerun`. If you can ignore the redundant file, this is the simplest solution, until there is first-class phony support.

**Use `action`**

You can write:

```
main = shake shakeOptions $ do
  action $ do
    need ["mytarget"]
    system' "ln" ["-s", "mytarget", "linkname"]
```

This declares an action that is run on every build. In reality you probably only want this to be run if `install` is on the command line, so you can do:

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  shake shakeOptions $ do
    when ("install" `elem` args) $ action $ do
      ... install code ...
```

**Use `shakeArguments`**

In the [later versions of shake](http://github.com/ndmitchell/shake) you can use the `shakeArgsWith` function to write:

```
main = shakeArgsWith shakeOptions [] $ \_ targets ->
  if "clean" `elem` targets then do
    removeFiles "_make" "//*"
    return Nothing
  else return $ Just $ do
    when ("install" `elem` targets) $ do
       ... install code ...
    ... other rules ...
    want $ delete "install" targets
```

This gives you full control over how the targets are processed, so you can do something far more powerful than phony targets, but its more work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow the first solution. I added `phony x f = x *> \o -> (alwaysRerun >> writeFile' x "" >> f o)` for now so that I can do `"install" 'phony' \_ -> do ...`

Comment: @Hudon, in shake-0.10 you can do a lot better - see my other answer (although this answer is still useful as the workarounds may be useful for other things).